# Can we train neural networks (ie with pytorch) within Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I was told we couldn't. Would we have to do it externally and then integrate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. See [Model Assets and Models Adapters](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/integrate-models/integrate-overview/).

Note: Without more information it will be hard to help you more. The minimal question length is there to encourage you to write down what you are facing, what you tested, and you tried or saw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! If you are using the [Model Training](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/model-integration/tutorial-train-code-repositories/#21-how-to-create-a-code-repository-for-model-training) library in Foundry you can build a PyTorch model like the simplified example below:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output
from palantir_models.transforms import ModelOutput
import palantir_models as pm
import palantir_models_serializers as pms

import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable


@transform(
    inferences_output=Output("/Palantir/Palantir Models Examples/linear_regression_pytorch/data/inferences_output"),
    model_output=ModelOutput("/Palantir/Palantir Models Examples/linear_regression_pytorch/models/pytorch_model"),
)
def compute(inferences_output, model_output=None):
    # create dummy data for training
    x_values = [i for i in range(100)]
    x_train = np.array(x_values, dtype=np.float32)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)

    y_values = [2 * i + 1 + np.random.normal(0, 1) for i in x_values]
    y_train = np.array(y_values, dtype=np.float32)
    y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)

    inputDim = 1        # takes variable 'x'
    outputDim = 1       # takes variable 'y'
    learningRate = 0.001
    epochs = 1000

    model = CustomModel(inputDim, outputDim)

    ##### For GPU #######
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.cuda()

    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Converting inputs and labels to Variable
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train).cuda())
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train).cuda())
        else:
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train))
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train))

        # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # get output from the model, given the inputs
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # get loss for the predicted output
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        print(loss)
        # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
        loss.backward()

        # update parameters
        optimizer.step()

    foundry_model = PyTorchModelAdapter(model)

    data = np.hstack((x_train, y_train))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y'])
    outputs = foundry_model.transform(df)

    inferences_output.write_pandas(outputs.df_out)
    model_output.publish(
        model_adapter=foundry_model
    )


class CustomModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(input_size, 3)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.output = torch.nn.Linear(3, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        return x


class PyTorchModelAdapter(pm.ModelAdapter):

    @pm.auto_serialize(
        model=pms.PytorchStateSerializer()
    )
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    @classmethod
    def api(cls):
        return {"df_in": pm.Pandas([('x', float)])}, \
               {"df_out": pm.Pandas([('x', float), ('prediction', float)])}

    def predict(self, df_in):
        df = df_in.astype('float32')
        x_inference = df['x'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

        with torch.no_grad():
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                predicted = self.model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_inference).cuda())).cpu().data.numpy()
            else:
                predicted = self.model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_inference))).data.numpy()

        df['prediction'] = predicted.reshape(-1)
        return df
```

This code above is adapted from [this towards data science post](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-with-pytorch-eb6dedead817) and uses dummy data generated in the training logic as well.

Comment: Awesome, can we train with gpu though? I see it on the code, but not sure if Foundry does that?

Comment: Yes you can train with GPUs, to do this you'll need to configure the transform to use GPUs. This is by adding the `@configure(profile=["DRIVER_GPU_ENABLED"])` configuration to your transforms logic. There can be some permissioning in order to get access to GPUs as well, you may need to be added to the relevant [resource profile](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/resource-management/resource-queues/#resource-queues).

Comment: @nweatherburn Is it possible to load HDF5 file ("model.h5") from local and use the model for prediction in code workbook or repo?

Comment: Hi @MahammadOjagzada, yes, you can follow [this documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/integrate-models/model-asset-files/). In summary, you upload your `.h5` file(s) into a dataset, and then publish this as a model asset in a Python transform.